# How do you send positions in joint_states topic if there's already default positions being published?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, joint-state-publisher, joint-states

By default `joint_state_publisher` publishes a message with all joints and default positions to the `joint_states` topic. What is the proper way of doing this? How do you take the preexisting message in `joint_states` and modify it to publish your own positions?

This code below is in a loop, publishing positions to `joint_states` but because there are 2 messages for the same joint, the joint wants to be in 2 different positions simultaneously.

```
sensor_msgs::msg::JointState joint_state_msg;
joint_state_msg.header.stamp = this->get_clock()->now();
joint_state_msg.name.push_back("joint_name");
joint_state_msg.position.push_back(position);
joint_state_publisher_->publish(joint_state_msg);
```

Console output below: `ros2 topic echo /joint_states`

```
--- // the default joint_state_publisher is publishing
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1704407222
    nanosec: 811950312
  frame_id: ''
name:
- joint_name
position:
- 0.0
velocity: []
effort: []
--- // position I want the joint to be
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1704407222
    nanosec: 911955095
  frame_id: ''
name:
- joint_name
position:
- 0.156
velocity: []
effort: []
---
```

I thought setting the `publish_default_positions` to false would remove the entire message from sending but it only makes `positions: []` instead of `positions: - 0.0`

```
Node(
    package="joint_state_publisher",
    executable='joint_state_publisher',
    name='joint_state_publisher',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[{'publish_default_positions': False}],
),
```

#### Reference

- https://index.ros.org/p/joint_state_publisher/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't start a `joint_state_publisher` node if you are already publishing to `joint_states` manually. That way there is only a single message being published to that topic.

Comment: In this example, looking at the launch file, they only start `robot_state_publisher` and another node publishes to `/joint_states`: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/URDF/Using-URDF-with-Robot-State-Publisher.html?highlight=robot%20state%20publisher#publish-the-state